# Error While importing pybrain in python shell

Tags: python, importerror, pybrain

I have tried to import pybrain and it gives me this error below.

`>>>import pybrain`

the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#33>", line 1, in <module>
    import pybrain
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pybrain\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pybrain.structure.__init__ import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pybrain\structure\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pybrain.structure.modules.__init__ import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pybrain\structure\modules\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pybrain.structure.modules.gate import GateLayer, DoubleGateLayer, MultiplicationLayer, SwitchLayer
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pybrain\structure\modules\gate.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pybrain.tools.functions import sigmoid, sigmoidPrime
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pybrain\tools\functions.py", line 4, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import inv, det, svd, logm, expm2
ImportError: cannot import name 'expm2' from 'scipy.linalg' (C:\Users\Rahul Bansal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\scipy\linalg\__init__.py)
```

or if try

`>>> from pybrain.structure.__init__ import *`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#34>", line 1, in <module>
    from pybrain.structure.__init__ import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pybrain\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pybrain.structure.__init__ import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pybrain\structure\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pybrain.structure.modules.__init__ import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pybrain\structure\modules\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pybrain.structure.modules.gate import GateLayer, DoubleGateLayer, MultiplicationLayer, SwitchLayer
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pybrain\structure\modules\gate.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pybrain.tools.functions import sigmoid, sigmoidPrime
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pybrain\tools\functions.py", line 4, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import inv, det, svd, logm, expm2
ImportError: cannot import name 'expm2' from 'scipy.linalg' (C:\Users\Rahul Bansal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\scipy\linalg\__init__.py)
```

please help me to import pybrain correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`scipy.linalg.expm2` has been [depreciated in version 0.13.0](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.0.13.0.html#expm2-and-expm3) (current version is 1.4.1). I don't know which one - [pybrain](https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain) or [pybrain3](https://github.com/AlexProgramm/pybrain3) package you use, but both look quite outdated - last commits in 2017

EDIT: You have 3 options:

- use version before 0.13.0 of scipy, not latest 1.4.1
- contact `pbrain` authors so that they make it compatible with latest versions of scipy or
- find alternative to `pbrain`.

Comment: I upgraded scipy to 1.4.1 current version but it didn't work too and my pybrain version is 0.3.1
any other solution?

Comment: You have 3 options - (i) use version before 0.13.0 of scipy, not latest 1.4.1, (ii) contact pbrain authors so that they make it compatible with latest versions of scipy or (iii) find alternative to pbrain.